# Summing a list of numbers from a text document

Tags: java, command-line-arguments

The goal is to create a program that scans a document with a list of numbers and sums the list of numbers. The program takes two command line arguments. The first argument tells how many lines to sum. The second argument tells which line to read. For example, if args[1]=2 that tells you to read every other line. Or if args[1]=3 that tells you to read every third line. 
Here is my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.io.*;

public class Lab8{  

    public static void main(String [] args)throws IOException {

        int intCount = 0;

        int sum=0;  

        File myFile;

        myFile=new File("nums.txt");

        Scanner in=new Scanner(myFile);

        if (args.length!=2){

            System.out.println("ERROR:NEEDS TWO CLA'S");

        }else{
            for(int i=0;i<Integer.parseInt(args[0]);i++){
                int x=in.nextInt();
                sum=sum+x;
            }

        }
            System.out.println(sum);        


    }
```

I get the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at Lab8.main(Lab8.java:33)
```

How can I fix my code? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the Scanner has anything to read using

```
Scanner.hasNextInt()
```

before your read it, [otherwise it will throw the exception you're seeing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29).

As for the "read every X line", you'll have to make a loop that reads the number of lines you want to skip before reading the one you want to store.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know If this achieves what you want:
*Note if your text file isn't in the same directory as your program you need to list the full File Path

```
public class Lab8{  
    public static void main(String [] args)throws IOException {


         int lineCount = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
         int skipCount = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

        int locaCount = 0;
        int sum=0;  
        File myFile;


        myFile=new File("nums.txt");

        Scanner in=new Scanner(myFile);

        if (args.length!=2){

            System.out.println("ERROR:NEEDS TWO CLA'S");

        }else{
            for(int i=0;i<lineCount; i += skipCount){
                int x=in.nextLine();
                sum+= x;
            }

        }
            System.out.println(sum);        


    }
```

Comment: This code compiled, runs and prints out a sum, but not the correct answer. The code works better than my original as it doesn't throw an error. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @VictoryGreen try this I don't why I subtracted one from the skipLine for the first version.

Comment: This fixed the program so that it outputs the correct answer when the second command line argument equals 1 (args[1]=1). I still need to fix it when args[1] is a value greater than 1.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (I didn't test the solution)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    // Check number of parameters at the begening
    // it is not needed to open file if there is no appropriate number of parameters
    if (args.length != 2) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: Need two parameters");
        return; // Or System.exit(1);
    }

    File myFile = new File("nums.txt");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(myFile);

    int totalLines = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int skipLines = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int currentLine = 0;
    int sum = 0;

    while (in.hasNext() && currentLine < totalLines) {
        int num = in.nextInt();
        if (currentLine % skipLines == 0) {
            sum += num;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Comment: This code compiles and runs, but it always prints out 48933 regardless of the command line argument. All i need to do is figure out some of the logic  for the while loop to output the correct answer. Thanks for the help!